# NodeJS variable with in Regex expression

Tags: node.js

How to I incorporate `find` variable, within a Regex ?

```
var find = 'de';
var phrase = 'abcdefgh';
var replace = '45';

var newString = phrase.replace(/de/g, replace)
```

i.e.: *var newString = phrase.replace(/*`find`*/g, replace)*

expected: `phrase = 'abc45fgh';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: The question is different, the answer is similar, but thanks anyway I missed that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

monkeyinsight's answer is great, but there is something else you should know. You need to be careful, depending on how `find` is constructed. Suppose that you have something like:

```
var name = 'Paul Oldridge (paulpro)';
var find = '/foo/(' + name + ')/bar';
```

Then you need to decide if you want to escape it for regex, so that it matches exactly the string `/foo/Paul Oldridge (paulpro)/bar` or if you want it to evaluate `name` as a regular expression itself, in which case `(paulpro)` would be treated as a capturing group and it would match the string `/foo/Paul Oldridge paulpro/bar` without the parenthesis around `paulpro`.

There are many cases where you might want to embed a subexpression, but more commonly you want to match the string exactly as given. In that case you can [escape the string for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2593637/772035). In node you can install the module `regex-quote` using npm. You would use it like this:

```
var regexp_quote = require("regexp-quote");

var name = 'Paul Oldridge (paulpro)';
var find = '/foo/(' + regexp_quote( name ) + ')/bar';
```

Which would correctly escape the parenthesis, so that `find` becomes:

```
'/foo/(Paul Oldridge \(paulpro\))/bar'
```

and you would pass that to the RegExp constructor as monkeyinsight showed:

```
new RegExp(find, 'g')
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `new RegExp()`

```
var newString = phrase.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
```